# Can QGIS2 / GDAL convert to .ECW without corruption?

Tags: qgis-2, ecw, raster-conversion

I have QGIS  2.0.1 and it can read *.ecw files that I download.

However, when I convert say a *.jpg or *.tiff to *.ecw the output is corrupt.

Has anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 5):

GDAL (and therefore QGIS) can only **read** ECW files. ECW is a proprietary file format, and one needs to buy the ERDAS-ECW-JP2 SDK to be able to write files.

More details [here](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/ERDAS-ECW-JP2-SDK/Details.aspx).

Comment: The link appears to be broken.