# Export from WMS Source to ECW file using QGis 2.18

Tags: wms, export, ecw, qgis-2.18

I create a new WMS connection using QGis 2.18 from this URL:

http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/WMS_v1.3/raster/ortofoto_colore_12.map

Now I want export to ECW file in according to specific coordinates.
I read some article about this but a the moment I'm not able to reproduce .ECW file output.

References:

[Using the python console to prepare offline maps from WMS (tile)](https://www.qgis.org/it/site/about/case_studies/india_pune.html)

[Generate Map Tiles with QGIS](https://mikeongis.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/printing-map-part-ii-map-tiles-with-qgis/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Free ECW SDK since version 4.x is read-only. With older SDK versions you are allowed to output ECW but only if the size of the source image is under the limit which I do not remember. I would consider using some free format, like tiled GeoTIFF with internal JPEG compression.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot export WMS in QGIS to ecw image format since it is a proprietary format (QGIS can only read that format), noted in the q/a below:

[Can QGIS2 / GDAL convert to .ECW without corruption?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82577/can-qgis2-gdal-convert-to-ecw-without-corruption)

You can use QGIS to convert to geotif than use another software to convert from geotif to ecw.